# Kungiliya Kalaya Nayanar

Tags: shiva, nayanar

Which is the birth place of this nayanar and what significance he has done to Saivism? Do not give the link Wikipedia. Apart from that any info thru ithihasas kindly quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Nayanars* are group of 63 saints devoted to Lord Shiva. They composed many songs to Lord Shiva in Tamil Language.

Their life stories and works are described in detail in *Periya Puranam* (great Purana), also called as *Tiruttontarpuranam* (*Tiru-Thondar-Puranam*, the Purana of the Holy Devotees).

Periya Puranam is available on shaivam.org in [Tamil](http://shaivam.org/siddhanta/thiru12.html) and [English](http://shaivam.org/english/sen_th12.htm) (Translated by Sri. T N Ramachandran).

Kungiliya Kalaya Nayanar is [11th Nayanar](http://www.dlshq.org/download/nayanar.htm#_VPID_14) among the 63 Nayanars.

Kungiliya Kalaya Nayanar was born in **Tirukadavur in the Chola kingdom** in a Brahmin caste.

Brief story of Kalaya Nayanar:

> By the will of Lord Siva, Nayanar became poor suddenly. He sold all
>   his property. His family was starving. Still, he continued to burn
>   incense before the Lord. One day his dutiful wife thought: ‘Everything
>   has been sold. Only this *Mangalyam* (a sacred thread with a pendant,
>   which every married woman must always have on her person, till the
>   husband dies, when it is removed), is left. I will give it to my Lord:
>   though it is inauspicious to do so. Let him sell it and obtain some
>   rice, with which we could feed the children who may die of hunger
>   otherwise.’ She removed the *Mangalyam* and gave it to her husband, who
>   gladly received it. As he was proceeding to the market to sell it,
>   Lord Siva Himself appeared before him, in the guise of a hawker and
>   said that he had very good **incense**. The word **incense** at once made
>   Nayanar forget himself and the mission! **He quickly bought incense for
>   the price of the Mangalyam, and went to the temple to burn it before
>   the Lord.**
>
> His wife patiently waited for his return, and, not finding him even
>   after nightfall, put the children to bed and remained praying. The
>   Lord was immensely pleased with this noble couple. The faithful wife
>   was prepared to part with even the most sacred ornament for the
>   service of her lord, her husband. The Kural says: ‘Rain falls at the
>   bidding of her who, on waking from sleep, worships no other God but
>   her husband.’ That night Lord Siva appeared in her dream and blessed
>   her with all wealth.

You can read more about him from [here](http://shaivam.org/devotees/the-history-of-kungiliyak-kalaya-nayanar).

You can read his works or songs  from [here](http://shaivam.org/thirumurai/twelveth-thirumurai/836/periya-puranam-ilai-malintha-charukkam-kunkuliyak-kalaya-nayanar-puranam) in Tamil and from [here](http://shaivam.org/devotees/the-puranam-of-kungkuliya-k-kalaya-nayanar) in English.

Comment: It is a copy and paste form the other link which I have seen.

Comment: ok. So, from where do you want? Anyways, that is Periya Puranam.